# Django ORM on a long running process: [2006, u'MySQL server has gone away']

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a long running process, (an crossbar.io python component) wich uses the django ORM for saving on a database.

My problem is that when it overpasses the mysql idle connection timeout, it doesnot auto-reconnects, just throw `[2006, u'MySQL server has gone away']`

I have tried defining CONN_MAX_AGE in django settings to 60 seconds, so it should close the connection every minute, and reopen it on demand, but it does not seems to work.

My settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60  
    }
}
```

And in the app, I just use normal simple CRUD model operations, without doing it by hand (as it seems to disable the autoreconnection feature of django, as said in other similar questions)

Comment: any resolution on this? facing the same issue